# How to import vcf file using the android internals built int classes

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I am trying to import a vcf file using the android built in classes: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/vcard

I have been searching for a while on how to do this with no luck. I also cannot use an external library like ez-vcard or something like that, and cannot use and intent to import the vcf file either as I want the import to be automatically without user interaction. Thanks in advance!!

Any reference or example I could get would be great!

Comment: Asking for off-site resources [is considered to be off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). With that in mind, and considering that Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions, what is your question?

Comment: How to import VCF file using Android internal classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the code found in the [ez-vcard-android](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android) project.  The project converts ez-vcard objects to the Android vCard data model.  It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: As I mentioned before I cannot use a library, my only choice would be to use these android built classes.

Comment: @perro123: You don't have to use the library.  Just look at the *source code* of the ez-vcard-android project.  It may give you some ideas on how to use the android built-in classes.